# Advanced Ratio Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, ratio

I have a video game(Factorio, if you have heard of it) that I like to play that involves many different kinds of ratios in order to optimize the production of items that require other items. Normally I can solve for the ratios, but this one is a little more complicated. Here is the problem:

I have 3 different kinds of factories in my setup. For simplicity, we will call them `X`, `Y`, and `Z`. We will also have 3 different products we will be discussing, which we will call `H`, `L`, and `G`.

Factory `X` takes no input(it does, but it is a fourth product that can be supplied unlimited from an external source, so shouldn't be needed to solve the problem), and produces all three outputs. It produces `55.575` of `H`, `100.035` of `L`, and `122.265` of `G`.

Factory `Y` takes `H` as an input, and has L as an output. It consumes `131` of `H` and produces `127.725` of `L`.

Factory `Z` takes `L` as an input, and has `G` as an output. Is consumes `98.25` of `L` and produces `65.5` of `G`.

The problem to solve is to find the ratio of `X:Y:Z`(where `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are all greater than zero) that will avoid any excess product of `H` or `L`, leaving only `G` as the net output.

I am pretty sure that this problem falls in the realm of Linear Algebra(which I admittingly have only a basic knowledge of), something to do with matrices and/or simultaneous equations. Trying to solve for `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, though, would require 3 equations, and I have sadly only been able to come up with either 2, or a third at the cost of accidentally creating a fourth unknown.

Here is what I have tried thus far, in case I was on the right track:

First attempt:

`0 = H = 55.575X - 131Y + 0Z`

`0 = L = 100.035X + 127.725L - 98.25Z`

`G = 122.265X + 0Y + 65.5Z`

**(Doesn't work due to creating fourth unknown, G)**

Second attempt:

`Y = (55.575X)/131`

`Z = (100.035X + 127.725Y)/98.25`

**(Doesn't work due to only having 2 equations)**

I would love to see the solution to this problem, and see what exactly I am missing here. Thank you in advance for any help!

EDIT:
From another source, I had a few people solving the problem. I am led to believe that there are too many unknowns to solve for a perfect ratio, and also that perhaps there may not actually be a completely perfect ratio. That said, with a ratio of `1000000000000 : 424236641221 : 1569675572520`, there is only a `0.000000000088752720331681537543048644709316% error` from whatever the perfect ratio would be, which in incredibly close. I will follow up with the person's calculations to obtain said ratio.

EDIT:
Turns out that it is a repeating decimal answer, so the above was not in simplest form. In its simplest form, the answer is `52400:22230:82251`

EDIT:
Corrected type on second equation, changing 100.032 to 100.035

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go back to your first attempt. We have the system of equations:

\begin{align}
0 &= 55.575X - 131Y + 0Z \\
0 &= 100.032X + 127.725Y - 98.25Z \\
G &= 122.265X + 0Y + 65.5Z
\end{align}

Now we have four unknowns, but remember we're just trying to find a ratio between $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. This means we can fix any of them at $1$ and find the ratio from there. Let $X=1$, and we will find.

\begin{align}
0 &= 55.575 - 131Y\\
0 &= 100.032 + 127.725Y - 98.25Z \\
G &= 122.265+65.5Z
\end{align}

We can solve this system now, I used WolframAlpha to do so and got $$G=\frac{900307}{4000}, X = 1, Y = \frac{2223}{5240}, Z = \frac{411247}{262000}$$

Now we wish to find integer results for $Y$ and $Z$ so we multiply and find $$262000: 111150: 411247$$ as the ratio $X:Y:Z$.

I've now checked my work by plugging it back into the original equations and find an output of $G = 5.89701\cdot 10^7$.

Happy engineering!

Comment: I believe where your answer and mine differ is a typo in your second equation. I can see that I actually made the same typo(the correct number is in the original problem description). 100.032 should be 100.035. That said, I think that we came to the same result, with your solution being a multiple of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Scale the production numbers of Process X such that the production of H in all three processes then nets to zero. Note the increase in production of L and G.

Scale the production numbers of Process Z such that the production of L in all three processes then nets to zero. Note the increase in production of G.

Well that's when working with

Process X: 55.575H + 100.035L + 122.265G

Process Y: -131H + 127.725L + 0G

Process Z: 0H - 98.25L + 65.5G

then

Process X scales with 2.3572

Process Y scales with 1.0

Process Z scales with 3.7 .

Finally, the solution-set can be scaled to integer values.

Comment: So, are you suggesting that I should approach it as two separate ratio problems?

Comment: I used H, L, and G as production products and not as variables. I scale the production numbers of Process X with 2.3572, Process Y with 1.0, and Process Z with 3.7 .

Comment: Relating to another answer, Y = 2223 / 5240 and that equals to 1 / 2.3572 as the scalar of Process Y divided by the scalar of Process X . Then Z = 411247 / 262000 and that equals to 3.7 / 2.3572 as the scalar of Process Z divided by the scalar of Process X. Also, X = 1 and that equals to 2.3572 / 2.3572 as the scalar of Process X divided by the scalar of Process X.